# Java EE 7 Nullpointerexception on dependency injection when test it in tomcat

Tags: java, dependency-injection, websocket

I am using an application that uses websockets and has based me on this example: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html

When I try the application from Netbeans IDE everything works correctly, but when I create the war file, I enter it in tomcat and I do the tests there I get a nullpointerexception error when trying to use a function of an injected class.

Code:

```
@ApplicationScoped
@ServerEndpoint("/chat")
public class ChatWebSocketServer {
...
@Inject
private ChatSessionHandler sessionHandler;
...
@OnOpen
public void open(Session session){
    ...
    usr.setSession(session);

    sessionHandler.addUser(usr); //-> throw nullpointerexception
}
```

Declaration of my ChatSessionHandler:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ChatSessionHandler {
```

When the exception occurs automatically onerror is called and the session is terminated.

**UPDATE**

tomcat by itself does not support CDI, i needed use TomEE. now works fine

Comment: If you rely on a dedicated `SessionHandler` class, what is the point of having your `ServerEndpoint` annotated with `@ApplicationScoped`? Unrelated but agreed with @ChiefTwoPencils: put **just** the necessary code.

Comment: I used oracle document to do the webapp. I have updated the post with the code where the exception occurs and how I declare the class.

Comment: basically the dependency injection does not work when I run it on my tomcat server. if I test in the netbeans everything works correctly, maybe I'm skipped some step, some configuration file or something similar.

Comment: tomcat by itself does not support CDI, i need use TomEE, now works fine.